# Combinatorics Urn Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have 208 unique marbles:

- From this 208, I select 15 marbles without replacement and place them into an urn.
- I do this again with a new urn, 3 more times, but using the original
  208 marble set, so I apply replacement after each selection of 15.
- I now have 4 urns of 15 marbles each, with no duplicate marbles within
  a particular urn, but possibly duplicates across urns.

What is the probability that there are exactly 14 marbles that appear in more
than 1 urn $?$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: An easier question is the expected number of marbles appearing in more than one urn, which seems to be about $5.883$, so the probability that there are exactly $14$ marbles that appear in more than $1$ urn is probably small, perhaps of the order of $0.02$ though I may be wrong

Comment: This doesn't address the original question, but can you clarify how you arrived at your answer?

Comment: Consider the probability that a particular ball appears in 0 or 1 urns.

Comment: The original question seems very difficult (although I may be missing some elegant approach). Where did you find this question?

Comment: @angryavain I realize it is difficult but this scenario happened in real life (though not with marbles) and was shocked and would like to know the probability...

Comment: Typically we care not about the probability of a particular outcome, but of a collection of outcomes that are "more extreme" than the one you see. For instance, the probability of flipping $n/2$ heads in $n$ tosses is approximately $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$ which might seem like a small number, but is actually the most likely outcome; looking at that number alone is not really going to give you a sense of how surprising it is. Similarly, in poker the probability that you get any particular hand is equal to the probability of getting a royal flush in hearts.

Comment: If you get $75$ coin flips in $100$ tosses, you usually look at the probability of "getting $\ge 75$ coin flips" (rather than "getting $=75$ coin flips") to get a sense of how surprising it is. In your situation you might reconsider asking for the probability of $\ge 14$ marbles appeared in more than one urn if you want a sense of how surprising getting $14$ marbles was. (Not sure if this is any easier to compute though.)

Comment: I appreciate the engagement but no one has attempted to solve the original question, which is clear

Comment: Each of those $14$ reappearing marbles may have multiple combinations - some of them may appear in $2$ urns while some in $3$, some in $4$ or a scenarios where all $14$ appear in two urns (and only $1$ in those two urns from the rest of the marbles). Very tedious.

Comment: Exploring the simpler problem of 2 urns, I got $$\frac{\binom{208}{14}(208-14)(208-15)}{\left[\binom{208}{15}\right]^2}.$$  From this, I agree with @MathLover that the math gets ugly fast.  I was tempted to apply https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/.  However, I'm not qualified to have an opinion on the validity of applying the principle here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
count = np.zeros(208)
rng = np.arange(208)
exactly14 = 0
morethan14 = 0
history = []
for i in range(4):
    choice = np.random.choice(rng, 15)
    history.append(choice)
    count[choice] += 1
for i in tqdm(range(100000)):
    choice = np.random.choice(rng, 15)
    count[choice] += 1
    history.append(choice)
    count[history[0]] -= 1
    history.pop(0)
    ccount = count[count > 1].sum()
    if ccount == 14:
        exactly14 += 1
    if ccount > 14:
        morethan14 += 1

print(exactly14/100000)
```

0.11

IMHO this problem suffers from combinatorial explosion thus it's easier to go with monte-carlo

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from Quester I simulated the problem with Monte Carlo

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
count = np.zeros(208)
rng = np.arange(208).astype(int)
urns=np.zeros([4,15]).astype(int)
exactly14 = 0
morethan14 = 0
lessthan14 = 0
history = []

for i in tqdm(range(1000000)):
    for j in range(4):
        urns[j, :] = np.random.choice(rng, 15, replace=False)

    n_unique=len(np.unique(np.ravel(urns)))
    n_multi=len(np.ravel(urns))-n_unique
    history.append(n_multi)
    if n_multi == 14:
        exactly14 += 1
    if n_multi > 14:
        morethan14 += 1
    else:
        lessthan14+=1

print(exactly14/1000000)
```

0.000489